# iOS Facebook SDK - Check Permissions

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook

I have a Facebook SSO working perfectly on my app, using last release of Facebook Objective-C SDK.
I need to ask an extra permission inside the app if user do "something". I don't need to ask that permission if user gave it to me before, so, I guess, in Facebook SDK there should be a method

```
-(BOOL) checkPermission:(NSString*) permission;
```

so I can use it like this:

```
if( [facebook checkPermission:@"email"] ) {
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This question is a bit old but you can now check what permissions the active session has without making a graph request. Here is how it's done in the HelloFacebookSample :

```
if ([FBSession.activeSession.permissions indexOfObject:@"publish_actions"] == NSNotFound) {
    // permission does not exist
} else {
    // permission exists
}
```

Just replace "publish_actions" with "email".

Comment: `[FBSession activeSession].permissions` returns the permissions you requested, not the active ones. Or at least that's what I saw. See my answer below. You need `[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/permissions" completionHandler:...]`.

Comment: I cannot test right now but the documentation says otherwise : "The permissions granted to the access token during the authentication flow."
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSession/

Comment: Today I updated my Facebook SDK pod from 3.9.0 to 3.15.1 and now `[FBSession activeSession].permissions` returns the right permissions and `[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/permissions" completionHandler:...]` doesn't return them anymore (now it returns {status:granted, permission:installed}).

Answer (score 7):

SDK not providing direct method for checking specific permissions but you can check if user granted permission to your application by checking `permissions` connection of [`user` object](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) in [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions
```

Same can be achieved with [FQL](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/) query on [`permissions` table](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/permissions/)

```
SELECT email FROM permissions WHERE uid = me()
```

Comment: Thank you, based on your answer, I tried using the method `[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/permissions" andDelegate:self];`. Implementing the delegate method it works perfectly. Thank you again

Comment: Could you add the code for your method to determine if the e-mail permission was active or not? What will 'email' be if the permission is granted?

Answer (score 0):

**IMPORTANT: This seems to be true for an older version of the Facebook SDK (for example 3.9.0). In 3.15.0 it doesn't work this way anymore. You should use `[session.permissions]` as Raphaël Agneau says in his answer.**

You have to use the following method, because `[FBSession activeSession].permissions` seems to return the permissions you requested, not the real ones.

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/permissions"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *c, id result, NSError *error) {
  if (!error) {
    NSDictionary *permissions= [(NSArray *)[result data] objectAtIndex:0];
    if (![permissions objectForKey:@"publish_actions"]) {
      // Ok, continue with your logic
    } else {
      // Permission not found, maybe request it (see below)
    }
  } else {
    // Treat error
  }
}];
```

See here for more info:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.0#permissions-checking

If the permission is not found you may want to request it this way:

```
[session requestNewPublishPermissions:PERMISSIONS_YOU_WANT
                      defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                    completionHandler:^(FBSession* session, NSError* error) {

    // Try again the /me/permissions above
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my code for FBSDK 4.2.0 for checking permissions.  The string that's passed in is the name of the permission, e.g. "publish_actions"

```
- (void) checkForPermission:(NSString *)permission granted:(void (^)(void))sBlock denied:(void (^)(void))fBlock {

  if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {

    [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me/permissions" parameters:nil] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

        BOOL hasPermission = NO;

        if (!error) {

            NSArray *permissions = [result objectForKey:@"data"];

            for (NSDictionary *dict in permissions) {

                if ([[dict objectForKey:@"permission"] isEqualToString:permission]) {

                    if ([[dict objectForKey:@"status"] isEqualToString:@"granted"]) {

                        hasPermission = YES;
                    }
                }
            }
         }

        if (hasPermission) {

            (sBlock) ? sBlock() : sBlock;

        } else {

            (fBlock) ? fBlock() : fBlock;
        }
     }];

  } else {

    (fBlock) ? fBlock() : fBlock;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the SDK 4+ you have these 2 ways of getting the permissions:

```
[[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] hasGranted:@"user_photos"]
```

or

```
[[[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] permissions] containsObject:@"user_photos"]
```